# angular2 ionic2 - how insert data request json into database sqlite

Tags: json, sqlite, angular, ionic2

I need to insert some data in JSON format from a request into a SQLite database in my app. The database is working and the table exists, but I don't know how to make this function insert into the table. 
Following is my code so far. Why is it not doing the INSERT?

```
synchronizeData() {
    let db = new SQLite();

    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Sincronizando..."
    });
    loader.present();
    this.account.allAccounts()
        .subscribe(data => 
        {
            this.list = [];
            //if (data.rows.length > 0) {
            console.log(data.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    this.AccountId = data.rows.item(i).Id;
                    this.AccountIdentification = data.rows.item(i).Identification;
                    this.AccountActive = data.rows.item(i).Active;
                    this.AccountEditionUserId = data.rows.item(i).EditionUserId;
                    this.AccountEditionDateTime = data.rows.item(i).EditionDateTime;
                    this.AccountAccountTypeId = data.AccountType.rows.item(i).Id;
                    this.AccountComplement = data.rows.item(i).Complement;
                    this.AccountPriceListId = data.rows.item(i).PriceListId;
                    this.AccountColor = data.rows.item(i).Color;
                    this.AccountReferenceKey = data.rows.item(i).ReferenceKey;

                    if (data.rows.item(i).Active == 'true') { this.AccountActive = 1 } else { this.AccountActive = 0 }
                    //this.results.push({ name: data.rows.item(i).name });
                    this.db.executeSql("INSERT INTO Accounts" +
                        "(Id, SId, Identification, Active, EditionUserId, EditionDateTime, AccountTypeId, Complement, PriceListId, Color, ReferenceKey)" +
                        "VALUES(" + this.AccountId + ", 0 ," + this.AccountIdentification + " , " + this.AccountActive + " , " + this.AccountEditionUserId + "," +
                        this.AccountEditionDateTime + ", " + this.AccountAccountTypeId + "," + this.AccountComplement + "," + this.AccountPriceListId + "," +
                        this.AccountColor + "," + this.AccountReferenceKey +
                        ")", []).then((data) => {
                            console.log("insert", data);

                        }, (error) => {
                            console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                        },
                        () => {
                            loader.dismiss();
                        })
                }
            //}

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you opening that database

```
synchronizeData() {
    let db = new SQLite();
    db.openDatabase({
      name: "data.db",
      location: "default"
    }).then(() => {
      let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
       content: "Sincronizando..."
        });
       loader.present();
       this.account.allAccounts()
       .subscribe(data => 
       {
           if(data){

              this.list = [];
              /* the rest of your code */
           } else {
             console.log("oops! data is undefined?!");
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: the database is open

Comment: ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:

Comment: ypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (main.js:57339)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (main.js:45010)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (main.js:44959)
    at Subscriber._next (main.js:44912)
    at Subscriber.next (main.js:44876)
    at MapSubscriber._next (main.js:107682)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (main.js:44876)
    at XMLHttpRequest.XHRConnection.response.__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.onLoad (main.js:55006)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (main.js:35923)

Comment: The error you are getting does not seem to have anything to do with your SQLIte.  it looks like data is undefined, so when you are trying to get the 'length' property it fails. I suggest putting a 'if' to check for data not being long. I edited the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
insertIntoTable(query: any) {
        this.database.openDatabase({
            name: this.nameDb,
            location: this.locationDb
        }).then(() => {
            this.database.transaction((tx) => {
                this.database.executeSql(query, {}).then((data) => {

                }, (error) => {
                    console.error("Unable to execute sql", error);
                }), (error) => {
                    console.error("Unable to open database", error);
                }
            })
        });
    }
```

this is a solution

```
synchronizeData() {

    this.querys.selectAllTablesExists;

    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "Sincronizando..."
    });
    loader.present();


    this.AccountService.allAccounts()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.list = [];
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    this.AccountId = data[i].Id;
                    this.AccountIdentification = data[i].Identification;

                    this.AccountEditionUserId = data[i].EditionUserId;
                    this.AccountEditionDateTime = data[i].EditionDateTime;
                    this.AccountAccountTypeId = data[i].AccountType.Id;
                    this.AccountComplement = data[i].Complement;
                    this.AccountPriceListId = data[i].PriceListId;
                    this.AccountColor = data[i].Color;
                    this.AccountReferenceKey = data[i].ReferenceKey;

                    if (data[i].Active == true) { this.AccountActive = 1 } else { this.AccountActive = 0 }
                    this.querys.insertIntoTable("insert or replace into Account (Id, SId, Identification, Active, EditionUserId, EditionDateTime, AccountTypeId, Complement, PriceListId, Color, ReferenceKey) VALUES('" + this.AccountId + "', '0' ,'" + this.AccountIdentification + "' , '" + this.AccountActive + "' , '" + this.AccountEditionUserId + "','" + this.AccountEditionDateTime + "', '" + this.AccountAccountTypeId + "','" + this.AccountComplement + "','" + this.AccountPriceListId + "','" + this.AccountColor + "','" + this.AccountReferenceKey + "')")

                }

                loader.dismiss();

            }

        })
    }
```